# Convergence issues in imputation model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, missing-data, mice

My glm model contains repeated measures of smoking (main exposure, binary:0,1), alcohol (binary 0,1), visit(binary1,0), education ("polr" with three levels 1,2,3), calorie (polr with 5 levels) and outcome as DMFT index in children (no missing) at multiple time points of 6months, 5, 9, 13 years.

All the variables are in a wide format and are considered as separate variables. My missing data mechanism seems to be completely at random (Missing of Maternal smoking is unrelated to dental caries in children)

I chose imputation methods as follows:

<method[c("smoking_6m","smoking_5y,""smoking_9y""smoking_13y""alcohol_6m", "alcohol_5y","alcohol_9y", "alcohol_13y","visit_5y", "visit_13y")] <- "logreg"

<method[c("calorie_5y","calorie_9y","calorie_13y, "education")] <- "polyr" <method

However after running the imputations the model doesn't converge.

The imputation model works if I set the change the method from "logreg" to "pmm", however i assume that "pmm" is used for continuous variables mostly and very less literature shows it can be used for categorical variables. Can I conclude valid results from this?

I observed the correlation plot and the smoking, alcohol and calorie variables are highly corelated to other time points, can this be a multicollinearity issue?

Can Inverse probability weights can solve this issue?